# How to get the size of belong_to record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/ruby-on-rails/tutorial/threaded-comments-polymorphic-associations) for making the exact same comments section on my website and now i want to display the number of comments on the article but I can only have the number of answers to the article without including the number of answers of comments.

I don't want to add a column to my comment model with a reference of the article ID because my website is already online and all the old post will have 0 comments because they will not have this new column.

Any idea of how I can do ? I guess it as something to do with `belong_to` but on the official doc I cannot find it.

My `model/comment.rb`

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  serialize :report, Array

  validates :commenter, presence: true, length: { in: 1..500 }
end
```

my `model/article.rb`

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  include BCrypt
  serialize :view, Array
  serialize :upvote, Array
  serialize :report, Array


  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { in: 1..60 }
  validates :content, presence: true
  has_secure_password

end
```

EDIT:

Maybe I could do a method in my helper with a loop which will count every comment of a comment, but I don't how I could make this loop like `Article.find(my_article_id).comments.each do` and then I don't know how to do, then maybe I should do like `Comment.comments.each do` ?

I was thinking to do a recursive method but I always struggle to do recursive method

EDIT2:

`schema/article`

```
  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "author"
    t.string "author_ip"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.text "content"
    t.string "upvote"
    t.integer "upvote_count", default: 0
    t.string "view"
    t.integer "view_count", default: 0
    t.string "report"
    t.integer "report_count", default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "activate", default: true
    t.integer "comments_count", default: 0, null: false
  end
```

`schema/comment`

```
create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "commenter"
    t.string "author"
    t.string "author_ip"
    t.string "date"
    t.integer "commentable_id"
    t.string "commentable_type"
    t.string "report"
    t.integer "report_count", default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "article_id"
  end
```

EDIT3:

`comment migration`

```
class AddCommentsCountToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :comments, :comments_count, :integer, default: 0,  null: false

    Comment.reset_column_information # to reset cached values
    Comment.find_each do |comment|
      comment.update(comments_count: comment.comments.count) # updating old articles comments_counter
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `article.comments.size` but it's not ideal as it will always make queries to the database.

Another way is to add counter cache `comments_count` column in your `articles` model, also you can update `comments_count` for any article created prior to the counter cache in the same migration.

You can start by adding migration

```
  def change
    add_column :articles, :comments_count, :integer, default: 0, null: false

    Article.reset_column_information # to reset cached values
    Article.find_each do |article| 
      article.update(comments_count: article.comments.count) # updating old articles comments_count
    end
  end
```

Now if you ran the migration and checked in the console for articles made prior to this migration, `comments_count` should reflect the number of comments for articles.

Now, the last step is to add `counter_cache` option to your `comment` model.
The `counter_cache` option makes sure the number in `comments_count` column is always updated whenever a comment is added or removed.

`belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true, counter_cache: true`

Now to get the cached value, you can either use:

- `article.comments.size`, as if you use a `counter_cache` on a has_many association, `size` will use the cached count directly, and won't make any queries at all.
- `article.comments_count`.

Similarly, to have `comment.comments.count` or `comment.comments_count` cached value, you need also to add another counter cache for `comments` table.

To get all the comments including nested comments for specific `article`, you need to get the article comments count(outer comments) + each comment comments count.

```
article.comments_count + article.comments.sum(:comments_count)
```

To DRY your code if you need to reuse it, you can add a instance method inside your `article` model as so:

```
def comments_count_including_nested
  comments_count + comments.sum(:comments_count)
end
```

Then you can call `article.comments_count_including_nested`

Comment: Thank you! I tried your method, the migration worked really well but when I try to add new comment I got `can't write unknown attribute `comments_count` and I don't understand why

Comment: What is the name of counter cache column you added in migration?

Comment: I named it `comments_count` same as your example

Comment: Were you trying to create a comment for comment or comment for post?

Comment: A comment for a comment. Comment for a post is working well

Comment: Have you added counter cache migration as well to your `comments` table?

Comment: I think I missunderstand your solution then, I did this `belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true, :counter_cache => true` but it's not what you are talking about right ?

Comment: Can you add db schema for `comments` and `articles` in your question?

Comment: You don't have `comments_count` in `comments` table, that's why you getting the error `can't write unknown attribute comments_count`. You have done the counter cache part for `articles` but not for `comments`. So you need to add another counter cache migration in your comments table. Tell me if  you got stuck, or need more information.

Comment: I can now create a comment of comment but in my view when I do `article.comments_count` or `article.comments.size` it doesn't count them. Only the comment of article. I have added my comments migration

Comment: What is the output of `article.comments_count` in the views? Can you try it in the console for both `comment.comment_count` & `article.comment_count` and tell me the result?

Comment: I have 2 comments of article and one comment of comment, and the article.comment_count return 2 instead of 3. I think it's because in my method create of comment I didn't do +1 to comment_count ?

Comment: I have got `undefined method '+' for #<Comment:0x00007fb848b9ea08>`. `sum` is returning a Comment not an integer. Doesn't will execute one query per parent comment ?

Comment: Work perfectly now, thank you for your time and your precious tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of comments and child comments like this:

```
article.comments.sum { |comment| 1 + comment.comments.count }
```

However, this will execute one query per parent comment on your article, which is not ideal.

Other ways of doing this:

- adding an `article_id` to all comments, and filling the current ones with a migration
- using a counter cache on comments

Comment: Thank you, it's helping a lot. So i add the column article_id and populate it on other existing ? In this case I have to do a method who give the good article_id to every comments, right ?

Comment: Yes, a migration could do that. You can infer the article_id from the `commentable` or the `commentable`'s parent.